# Creating dependent resources that can be configured

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

### Description

Currently I'm creating some Cucumber features for a service. Let's say I have a service that is used for configuring Tesla cars:

```
public class TeslaCar {
    Engine engine;
    Color color;
    // other things here...
}
```

where

```
public class Engine {
    boolean isAllWheelDrive;

    // for 60, 70, 90D, P100D
    KilowattEnum kWh;

    // other things here...
}
```

The simple *create* calls are easy to implement, I just use `Given` combined with `Add` to configure the resources then call the *create*.

So for `CreateEngine`, I'd do:

```
Feature: CreateEngine
    Scenario Outline: Create Engine
        Given an engine was initialized
          And engine has <all_wheel>
          And kwh is <kwh>
        When engine is created
        Then engine creation succeeds

    Examples:
    | kwh | all_wheel |
    | 60  | false     |
    | 60  | true      |
    | 70  | false     |
```

And now I need to write an integration test for `DriveCar`. I want to use `Given` to ensure there is a new car that I can drive. I want to create a new car because I have no idea what the state of the past cars could be. If the battery level is at 10%, it won't be a good test. Then, since the integration test depends on the type of Tesla I have, I want to configure this in my feature file.

So it'd look like:

```
Feature: Drive Car
  Scenario: Test drive Tesla
    Given a car is initialized
      And engine kwh is P90D
      And engine is all wheel drive
      And engine is created
      # Need to call CreateEngine with above line, but is this clunky?
      And car is created
      # Need to call CreateCar above because Engine is a parameter to CreateCar
    When car is driven
    Then max speed is 120mph
```

### Problem

This seems pretty reasonable at first, but is there a better way to do this? If more things needed to be configured for `DriveCar`, then it would become unwieldy pretty fast.

### Questions

1. Is this bad practice for tests?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish this?
3. Am I not thinking the Cucumber way?

### Possible Solution 1?

One thing I thought of is to use `@tags`. This would let me say, 'I need a 60kWh engine whenever I use `@60kwh`'. But this doesn't extend well.

### Possible Solution 2?

Don't configure the car and instead just use a default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cucumber is designed for acceptance tests, tests which exercise the entire system (so they are also integration tests) as the user would and can be understood by stakeholders as well as by developers.

Your `CreateEngine` scenario isn't for the entire system, but for a software component that only has meaning to developers, so I'd test it not with Cucumber but with a unit-testing framework.

Your "Drive Car" scenario, on the other hand, is an appropriate acceptance test. It has a lot of software detail, though. I'd write it something like this:

```
Feature: Drive Car

  Scenario: Test drive Tesla
    Given there is a car with an all-wheel-drive engine and P90D engine kwh
    When the car is driven
    Then the max speed is 120 mph
```

(I'm not sure that "P90D engine kwh" is correct grammar, so please correct as necessary.)

Important points:

- There is no reference to software detail.
- Values that aren't important to the outcome aren't mentioned; they're just defaults. Note that if there are any other values that are important to the outcome, they should be mentioned too, so that the reader has all of the information in front of them needed to verify the correctness of the outcome, without having to read the step definitions. For example, if Teslas also had tail fins and tail fin size affected max speed, the step that defines the car should also mention "large tail fins" or whatever.

I'm not sure whether you need more flexible car definition steps than I showed or not. I usually find that only a few simple steps are needed in most scenarios. Try to stay simple at first and build more complicated steps only if you need them.

Also, resist the urge to write Cucumber scenarios (or scenario outlines) for all combinations of data. Acceptance tests are slow and and take work to maintain, so you want to have as few as you can while still exposing all of the important requirements to stakeholders. When you start writing combinatorial Cucumber scenarios, think whether you can instead write one Cucumber scenario as an example and test all the combinations in unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

I would compress the steps for adding a component to the car like the engine. Use a `DataTable` to add all the properties for the engine. From this new step definition, which will only take a `DataTable` as parameter, you can call existing code for engine setup. This way you do not need to add a new step definition every time you add a new property. Just append to the end of the DataTable.

If you have a new component for the car you need to add just 3 lines to your feature file plus a step definition. For example, I added a gearbox to the feature.

If in the feature file DataTable, you name your table headers same as instance variable then Cucumber will put the values in the class automatically if you put the parameter like `List<Engine> engine` instead of `DataTable`.

The problem I see is if you have a property with multiple settings. For example engine mode could be City, Cruise and Sport. Maybe you could use a comma separated string and then split it.

```
Feature: Drive Car
  Scenario: Test drive Tesla
    Given A car with following components

    And Add engine with specifications
      | kwh  | allwheel |
      | P90D | true     |

    And Add gearbox with specifications
      | noofgears  | auto |  
      | 4          | true |          

    And assemble car
    When car is driven
    Then max speed is 120mph
```

If you want some more fun consider making it a scenario outline and test out multiple combinations in one feature. But then you will have a big examples table row of data. I would actually use that route cause I will get more out of one scenario and it will push data out of steps and into the examples table.

The steps in the feature file seem like summarizing the code rather than the behavior like the step - an engine was initialized. But if everyone understands it and serves your purpose why change it.

Answer (score 2):

Really good question, and there is a great answer from Dave Schweisguth, which I'll add too.

When you have a structure like your car with all its configuration options and you want to write integration tests to deal with different sorts of cars you can remove the need for specifying the details of each care in your feature by naming the cars. For example I might have:

- Rally Car:  4 wheel drive, 6 gears, ultra-lightweight chassis,
  rollbar
- Taxi: 2 wheel drive, 4 gears, stain resistant interior
- Mid life crisis car: 4 wheel drive, coupe, drop top, leather interior ...

Then you would write features like:

```
Given I have a rally car
...

Given I have a taxi
```

etc. etc.

Now its important that in you whens and thens, that you don't resort to going back to details e.g

```
Given I have a taxi
Then I should have 2 wheel drive
And I should have 4 gears
```

is bad as you are mixing two levels of abstraction, the detailed one and the higher level one. Instead you should be writing taxi scenarios for taxi's

e.g.

```
Given I have a taxi
When my passengers puke over my interior
Then it should be easy to clean
```

This means that your names need to be important to your stakeholders.

One thing you get from this approach is a reduction in the cost of change when you change specifications. For example if we decide that taxi's should be 4wd we don't have to change every scenario, we just change the step def `Given I have a taxi'.

I would implement the step defs as follows

```
Given 'I have a taxi' do
  create_taxi
end

module TaxiStepHelper
  def create_taxi
    create_car(
      engine: 
      drive: 
      ...
     )
   end
```

I think of this approach as 'using a higher level abstraction'. But Matt Wynne came up with a great way of describing it which is 'pushing the HOW down'. What we are doing is pushing the responsibility for HOW the car is configured from the scenarios through the step definitions to a step definition helper.

Comment: Great comments. Thanks for the info. I also loved how you took my example further with `mid-life crisis car` and `puke over my interior`. Haha